# Does this swordsman pose have any significance?

Tags: one-piece, symbolism, fairy-tail

Does this pose of raising your sword with your right hand have any significance? For example, is this a famous pose used by a real life legendary swordsman? Both Zoro of One Piece and Erza of Fairy Tail have used this pose.

[image: Zoro's pose]
[image: Erza's pose]

Comment: Please let me know if the images used are a problem. I will replace them depending on what the problem is.

Comment: I don't think the images are a problem based on the replies I got to [this meta question](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-graphic-is-too-graphic).

Comment: The images are not a problem because they are *needed* to illustrate the question. In other words, they are not a problem because they are not added gratuitously.

Comment: good observation, correlating two anime like that. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think it is reference to anything specific since it's overly common whenever swords are (and sometimes when they aren't) involved in media.

In general:

- it looks cool
- it's usually a show of triumph by combining display of:

  - dominance (as other poses that make body "unwrap")
  - combat impracticality (no one is doing this in the middle of it)

tvtropes call it [StabTheSky](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StabTheSky).

Comment: And it shows the audience that the user can still rise his sword and isn't destroyed to the bone, maybe.

Comment: In both the above pictures, the characters took up the pose not during a battle, but to signify a "badass moment", so this makes sense. I think it would look quite lame if someone just stands in that pose for long during a battle. :P

Comment: Yep, that's under combat impracticality point - it can signify "everyone who can take advantage of me doing this posh vulnerable pose is lying around in pieces" - Erza's case. :)

Comment: Hmm, good to join this site. tvtropes looks like interesting. thanks for link. :):)

Comment: As said above. I would say it is not specific to anime / manga, Frazetta painted barbarians with this attitude long before manga was popular in the USA... See for example the http://galaxywarriorsbysungold.blogspot.fr/p/artwork.html page showing several of these poses.

Answer (score 4):

To add on to Rarst's answer, the pyramid-shaped stance naturally channels the viewer's gaze to the sword, especially to its tip. This places focus on the "warrior spirit", typical of a declaration of victory. The "warrior spirit" is raised to a high position by the stance, which further befits the idea of "dominance".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a hidden meaning behind this. In my opinion, it is just a pose that shows determination. It could be also used a salute. For example, a "classical" sword salute looks like this:

[image]

The Olympic Flame is also carried this way:

[image]

So I would say that this pose means just that, no special hidden meaning involved. And yeah, it also looks cool.